# How to add a python generated macro-script to an excel-file by xlsx-writer module?

Tags: python, vba, excel

I have a python script, which generates a vba written macro variable for excel. A preview of the variable looks kind like this:

```
macro = """Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

...

End Sub"""
```

In my python script I'm create a workbook with the xlsxwriter module and I would like to add this macro to my workbook within the python script. Does somebody know further information about this issue?

I've already tried it with `workbook.add_vba_project('./vbaProject.bin')`, but it isn't working until now.

Comment: How did you extract the `vbaProject.bin`? Did you use `vba_extract.py`